# Disabling com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink logging tomcat

Tags: dynamic-linking, logging, link-info

We have a size problem with our catalina.out.

We are configuring the `logging.properties` file and the `log4j.properties` files.  We are setting all of the log levels to `WARNING` or `ERROR`, but in `catalina.out` we still see `DEBUG` entries.

**Here is an example of some of the Deubg statements that we are seeing:**

> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   ComponentLink Found metadata for page: 79121
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   ComponentLink.getLink(): start retrieving pathinfo for this page:
>   79121
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   ComponentLink.getLink():
>   componentLinkInfo.getPageId()<>sourcePageId=81284=79121
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   Path to source page is: /cat/_include
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   Path to found page is :/cat/pagines-finals
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   Score found is 101
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   Found component with score 101
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   ComponentLink.getLink(): found a target page, using PageLink to link
>   to page: 81284
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink -
>   ComponentLink.getLink(): Anchor: null
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.PageLink -
>   PageLink.getLink(...) called to resolve link for page: 81284
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.PageLink -
>   PageLink.getLink(...) got URL from PageMetaData:
>   /cat/pagines-finals/notes-legals.jsp
>
> 14:08:16.644 [TP-Processor1] DEBUG com.tridion.linking.PageLink - PageLink.getLink(...) returning
>   link:

**Snippet code from our logging.properties:**
...

```
com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.level = WARNING 
com.tridion.linking.PageLink.level = WARNING
```

...

**Snippet code from our log4j.properties:**

...

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, FileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender.File=/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/web.log
log4j.appender.FileAppender.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.FileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %d %-5p: %m%n
```

...

**This makes our file sprocket grow significantly every day.**

How can we change the logging settings so that we only see warning errors (or above)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to change that setting in the logback.xml file available in your application classes folder.

```
<property name="log.level" value="WARN"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to change the log level on `log4j.properties` and `logging.properties`.

As **@Eric** mentioned, you need to update log level on `logback.xml`

Sample Logback file looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Properties -->
    ...
    ...
    <property name="log.folder" value="c:/tridion/log"/>
    <property name="log.level" value="ERROR"/>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
</configuration>
```

### List of Log Levels:

- ALL

  - The ALL is used to turn on all logging.
- DEBUG

  - The DEBUG level designates informational events of lower importance.
- ERROR

  - The ERROR level designates error events which may or not be fatal to the application.
- INFO

  - The INFO level designates informational messages highlighting overall progress of the application.
- OFF

  - The OFF is used to turn off logging.
- TRACE

  - The TRACE level designates informational events of very low importance.
- WARN

  - The WARN level designates potentially harmful situations.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the info given in the other answers, you can also disable linking logging completely by adding the following logger in logback.xml:

```
<logger name="com.tridion.linking" level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingCoreLog"/>
</logger>
```

Turning logging completely off is of course not very handy, in case errors occur when links are resolved. Setting the level to `ERROR` or `WARN`on live environments and to `DEBUG` on development environments is what I always do.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

We deployed the `logback.xml` file in wrong place.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Our logback.xml file was already set to ERROR.

```
    <property name="log.pattern" value="%date %-5level %logger{0} - %message%n"/>
<property name="log.history" value="7"/>
<property name="log.folder" value="/data/tridion/log"/>
<property name="log.level" value="ERROR"/>
```